# Python itertools - Combining groupby and recipe tools' grouper

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Say I have the following data:

```
data = [['John', 1], ['Ada', 2], ['Ada', 3], ['Paul', 4],
        ['Paul', 5], ['Paul', 6], ['Kat', 7], ['Kat', 8]]
```

I can group the entries by person with `groupby`:

```
In [37]:

from itertools import groupby, izip_longest
from operator import itemgetter

for name, g in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)):
    print name, list(g)

John [['John', 1]]
Ada [['Ada', 2], ['Ada', 3]]
Paul [['Paul', 4], ['Paul', 5], ['Paul', 6]]
Kat [['Kat', 7], ['Kat', 8]]
```

I can also group every two entries use the [recipe tools' grouper](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). I will copy/paste it for reference:

```
In [38]:

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

for g in grouper(data, 2):
    print g
(['John', 1], ['Ada', 2])
(['Ada', 3], ['Paul', 4])
(['Paul', 5], ['Paul', 6])
(['Kat', 7], ['Kat', 8])
```

But now, I want to iterate over the data such that the first element contains John and Ada's data, and the second element contains Paul and Kat's data. In other words, I would like to combine `groupby` and `grouper` like this:

```
In [39]:

person_iterator = groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))
for group_iterator in grouper(person_iterator, 2):
    print [(keyvalue[0], list(keyvalue[1])) for keyvalue in group_iterator]
```

But the output is not what I expected:

```
[('John', []), ('Ada', [['Ada', 2], ['Ada', 3]])]
[('Paul', []), ('Kat', [['Kat', 7], ['Kat', 8]])]
```

Why are there empty lists for John and Paul? How to fix it?

Comment: Exactly what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `iterator` yielded (`group_iterator[1]`) by `itertools.groupby` is exhausted when the next `iterator` is yielded.

You need to convert the iterators into sequences before passing it to `grouper` to prevent that:

```
person_iterator = ((key, list(grp)) for key, grp in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)))
for group_iterator in grouper(person_iterator, 2):
    print [(key, value) for key, value in group_iterator]
```

Output:

```
[('John', [['John', 1]]), ('Ada', [['Ada', 2], ['Ada', 3]])]
[('Paul', [['Paul', 4], ['Paul', 5], ['Paul', 6]]), ('Kat', [['Kat', 7], ['Kat', 8]])]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works but I still don't understand why the iterator is exhausted when the next iterator is yielded.

Comment: @usualme, If the iterator yielded by `groupby` is not exausted when the next iterator is yielded, some memroy should be used to hold it.

Comment: @usualme, I hope this ( http://ideone.com/I2lrWX ) help you to understand what I mean.

Comment: @usualme, Or considering how to implement `itertools.groupby` yourself will be also helpful. (not using unnecessary memory).